# Move files to folder but ignore certain ones

Tags: c#

I'm trying to move text files into a folder but ignore test.txt and all others will be moved to FileHolder folder. When I run it it still moves all the txt files to the folder.

```
private void testmodule()
{
    string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

    List<String> AllDeskTopFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.txt*").ToList();

    foreach (string file in AllDeskTopFiles)
    {
        if (file != "test.txt")
        {
            FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
            if (new FileInfo(d + "\\FileHolder\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
                mFile.MoveTo(d + "\\FileHolder\\" + mFile.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a hint, look at the actual values in `file` and your answer should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Psst, use Path.Combine, it'll make your life easier

Answer (score 2):

Your `file` variable contains the full path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter based on the file name, not the full path.

You could just do the filter in the LINQ statement:

```
var allDeskTopFiles = Directory
           .GetFiles(filepath, "*.txt*")
           .Where(f => !f.EndsWith("test.txt", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);


foreach (string file in allDeskTopFiles)
{
    // Move all files now
```

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.GetFiles` returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified directory.

So you need to apply a method to extract only the filename

```
  foreach (string file in AllDeskTopFiles)
    {
        if (Path.GetFileName(file).ToLower() != "test.txt")
        {
            FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
            if (new FileInfo(d + "\\FileHolder\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
                mFile.MoveTo(d + "\\FileHolder\\" + mFile.Name);
        }
    }
```

Also creating a FileInfo for every loop just to test the existence or not of the file seems a bit expensive

```
  string destPath = Path.Combine(filepath, "FileHolder");
  foreach (string file in AllDeskTopFiles)
  {
        string fileToMove = Path.GetFileName(file).ToLower();
        if (fileToMove != "test.txt")
        {
            string destFile = Path.Combine(destPath, fileToMove);
            if (!File.Exists(destFile))
                File.Move(file, destFile);
        }
   }
```

Comment: There is typo, Path.GetFileName(file=).ToLower()

Answer (score 0):

Following should fix it, A cleaner way now:

```
private void testmodule()
{
    string filepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);

    List<String> AllDeskTopFiles = Directory.GetFiles(filepath, "*.txt*").ToList();

    foreach (string file in AllDeskTopFiles)
    {
        //if (file.ToLower().EndsWith("test.txt"))
        //{
        //    FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
        //    if (new FileInfo(d + "\\FileHolder\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
        //        mFile.MoveTo(d + "\\FileHolder\\" + mFile.Name);
        //}
        FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
        if(mFile.Name.ToLower() != "test.txt")
        {
            if (new FileInfo(d + "\\FileHolder\\" + mFile.Name).Exists == false)
                mFile.MoveTo(d + "\\FileHolder\\" + mFile.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either check the file name, like this:

```
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("old");

        foreach (FileInfo fi in dirInfo.GetFiles("*.txt"))
        {
            if (fi.Name != "test.txt")
                File.Copy(fi.FullName, "new/" + fi.Name);
        }
```

Or change your code to check `if !file.Contains("text.txt")` instead of `if file != "test.txt`